# XML Deserialization with RestSharp in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, deserialization, restsharp

I'm new to RestSharp. And I use it in my Windows Phone 7.1 project.

I have a class **UserProfile**:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public string UserId {get; set}
    public string Phone {get; set}        
    public string Email {get; set}
    public string Firstname {get; set}
    public string Lastname {get; set}
    public bool Sex {get; set}
    public string Status {get; set}
    public DateTime CreatedDate {get; set}
    public string Online {get; set}
    public string Role {get; set}
    public string AppId {get; set}
    public string AppName {get; set}
    public string Token {get; set}      
}
```

I use RestSharp to send Http Request and receive response with XML format (corresponding with UserProfile class). How can I deserialize response content to UserProfile?

This is my code:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("http://myaddress");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
//...
//add parameters
//...

client.ExecuteAsync<UserProfile>(request, (response) =>   // <--------- right?
{
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show(response.Content);     //returned content is correct

        DotNetXmlDeserializer des = new DotNetXmlDeserializer();
        //UserProfile up = des.Deserialize<UserProfile>(...     <------- HOW ?

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
});
```

Please notice that there is no System.Xml.Serialization.**XmlSerializer** in Windows Phone.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `response.Data`, that is the deserialized object!

Comment: But there is no response.Data?

Comment: The Data property shows up if you are using `client.ExecuteAsync<UserProfile>()` if you aren't seeing it, you're probably using `client.ExecuteAsync()`

Comment: Can I make ExecuteAsync generic instead of specifying a concrete class? I tried with client.ExecuteAsync<T>() and it shows an error: "T must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor..."

Comment: If you use it like that, it won't be able to auto-deserialize (and no Data property will be available). But looking at the UserProfile class you have posted, that exception shouldn't rise... did you change the class?

Comment: I reduced UserProfile code to make it easier to see, not my real code. Thank a bundle!

Comment: Probably you removed the empty constructor; just add one to it and all should work fine!

Comment: If you wrap it you can make it generic, you just have to use the same constraints. Here's an example: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/master/src/Twilio.Api/Core.cs#L61